# Using nested python dataclasses with __post_init__ in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, python-dataclasses

I'm developing an API to expose some of the functionality of a large library that uses extensively python 3.10 native dataclasses. These dataclasses can be nested, and each one may have a `__post_init__` method to compute further attributes  after initialization that can be used in other classes. A simplified example of the library:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Material:
    f: float
    sf: float = 1.5
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.fd = self.f / self.sf

@dataclass
class Square:
    w: float
    material: Material
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.area = self.w * self.w
        self.force_max = self.material.fd * self.area
```

I'm using FastAPI to develop the API. First I tried:

```
@app.post("/square/")
async def root(square: Square):
    return {
        "area": square.area,
        "force_max": square.force_max,
    }
```

I also tried using the parameters from the request to initialize again the library dataclass `Square`:

```
@app.post("/square/")
async def root(square: Square):
    square = Square(
        w=square.w,
        material=Material(f=square.material.f)
    )
    return {
        "area": square.area,
        "force_max": square.force_max,
    }
```

In both cases I get the same error: the attributes created after `__post_init__` in the nested dataclass don't exist.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fd'
```

Is there any way to force the `__post_init__` of each dataclass so we can have access to all their attributes?

Answer (score 0):

This is how `__post_init__` works, it is not related to fastAPI, see how you can fix it:

```
@dataclass
class Square:
    w: float
    material: Material

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.area = self.w * self.w
        if isinstance(self.material, dict):
            self.material = Material(**self.material)
        self.force_max = self.material.fd * self.area


print(Square(w=10.1, material=Material(f=101.9)))

print(
    Square(
        **{
            "w": 10.1,
            "material": {"f": 101.9}
        }
    )
)
```

And your payload would be:

```
{
    "w": 10.1,
    "material": {"f": 101.9}
}
```